# how to solve this <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject for Instagram API JSON

Tags: java, android, json

i am trying to read the Instagram API JSON URL like this https://www.instagram.com/p/CO3s-HKg779/?__a=1 but when I am trying to get data from JSON for android I get this `<!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject` error. here is below my code I did this with AsyncTask. is there anyone who can help me with this issue, please.

````
private class FatchData extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

        ProgressDialog pd;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            pd = new ProgressDialog(ImageLoaderActivity.this);
            pd.setMessage("Fetching data...");
            pd.setCancelable(false);
            pd.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                okhttp3.Request request = new okhttp3.Request.Builder()
                        .url(JSON_URL)
                        .build();
                try {
                    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                    String jsonData = Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).string();
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonData);

                    DATA_TYPE = jsonObject.getJSONObject("graphql")
                            .getJSONObject("shortcode_media")
                            .getString("__typename");
                    Log.d("TAGD", "onResponse: DATATYPE "+DATA_TYPE);

                    IMAGE_URL = jsonObject.getJSONObject("graphql")
                            .getJSONObject("shortcode_media")
                            .getString("display_url");
                    Log.d("TAGD", "onResponse: IMAGE URL "+IMAGE_URL);




                } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.d("TAGD", "OkHttpCallData: Exception"+e.getMessage());
                }


            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            Log.d("TAG", "onPostExecute: Data Fatch Done");
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            if (pd!=null){
                pd.dismiss();
            }


        }
    }```
````

Comment: If you debug (or System.out.print) the `response` variable, you'll see that it contains HTML rather than JSON. This is likely due to Instagram sending you back an error message of some type. It is always a good idea to check the HTTP status code of the response prior to trying to process the unknown.

Comment: @RandyCasburn but when I click the link it's showing JSON in the browser. how can I check this HTTP status code? any resource? please

Comment: Look in your `import` statements to determine the source of your `Response` object and look at the JavaDoc for that implementation.

Comment: Assuming `OkHttp` is source of `Response`, then you can do: [response.isSuccessful](https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-response/is-successful/)

Comment: I tried with the `if` statement and it called `else` the response is not Success that means `boolean` value is `false`. now, what to do? how can I get this JSON data?

Comment: Fix your request and ensure you are using the correct authentication tokens. Good luck!